# Need help in building associations for my scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I am not well-versed in associations and don't have extensive knowledge in this section.

Following is my use-case:
There are two models:

- Employee
- Rating

--> Employee(as a team lead) can give ratings to his team members(employee)

Will it be a good idea to only take `has_many` relationship between `employee to rating`?
Also, I am bit confused, how I will be able to show ratings of team lead and their team members rating in `Team Lead` login session separately.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ratings` table should have a `giver_id` and an `employee_id` column. Then:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :given_ratings, foreign_key: :giver_id, class_name: Rating
  has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :giver, class_name: Employee
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

Then for any employee, the following should work:

```
team_lead = # fetch employee however
team_lead.ratings # ratings given TO this employee
team_lead.given_ratings # ratings given BY this employee
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting some error on team_lead.given_ratings.count. Log here http://goo.gl/gzwSts. Could you please check?

Comment: dude you need to add the `giver_id` column to your ratings. and mark my answer as the selected one if it answers your question.